# How can I show different content based on different domain name in same Ruby on Rails applications?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nginx, passenger

I have Ruby on Rails application, and store under path /var/www/apps, and I use Nginx and passenger to access this application, currently, I use two domain name to access this application, www.test.com and console.test.com, with Nginx, the conifguration file similar like this

```
    server_name www.test.com console.test.com;
    root /var/www/apps/current/public;
    passenger_enabled on;
    passenger_use_global_queue on;
    passenger_min_instances 3;
    ...
```

with this configuration, not only www.test.com but also console.test.com, there is same application content shown.

Question, I have a requirement, when clients access the application with different domain name, there is different application content shown to the client, example, when I access with domain name www.test.com, there is common content shown, when I access with domain name console.test.com, the console content shown, both contents are built in the same Ruby on Rails applications.

How can I do? configure for Nginx, for Passenger, or for Ruby on Rails?

Answer (score 0):

Usually this is done within Rails.

You might want to check this great tutorial on subdomains: https://github.com/RailsApps/rails3-subdomains

The main point is to see request.subdomain, and load contents (db records) accordingly.

Comment: Thanks, James. I think this is helpful for me. But this project is existed, and I am affraid that I add this new plugs-in into the project and update some dependences, the applications will be crashed. Is there any configuration way can do same thing?

Comment: No you don't need to add plug-ins. Just read how the example project does and write your own logic. IMO that's pretty simple and plain.